# Jasper ireport sql server - showing net.sourceforge.jtds. in final report preview

Tags: java, sql-server, jasper-reports, jtds

I am facing a problem with Jasper on MS SQL db. My final report is showing net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc. in result for each and every row and column. I configured a very simple select query. JrXML also compiled good to Jasper and placed the fields in details band. I have no idea whats going wrong. Please help me out.

Note: I am referring to jtds-1.3.1 jar through iReport

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly provide a sample JRXML of your design

Answer (score 0):

It is just the Variable type(field class value in iReport) of the field, in previous versions it used to automatically used to set to their original types. But it is default getting set to java.sql.clob in the version which I am using, seems a little weird.

Thank you